# How to find all those Sellers from the data frame who had increase in sales in at least 3 months?

Tags: python, sql

This is more of SQL question that needs to be implemented in both SQL and Python. I don't know SQL Query for this.

I have attempted this in python but it does't seems to be smart enough. Is there a better way to do it ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'Seller_id': [121,121,121,121,121,
                                  321,321,321,321,321,
                                  597,597,597,597,597,],
                    'Months': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May',
                              'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May',
                              'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May',],
                    'Sales_amount': [100,87,95,105,100,
                                    100,87,95,105,110,
                                    100,105,95,100,110]

})
df.head()
```

#### Data Extraction Code

```
df['diff_1'] = df.Sales_amount.diff(periods=1)

df.loc[df['Months'] == 'Jan', 'diff_1'] = np.nan

df_new = df[df['diff_1'] > 0]

df_new2 = df_new.groupby(['Seller_id'], as_index=False).agg({'diff_1':'count'})

df_new2.loc[df_new2['diff_1'] > 2, 'Seller_id']
```

Comment: Do you mean for at last three _consecutive_ months?

Comment: what does your table look like in SQL? maybe we can start with that to help you with your SQL query

Comment: @Giorgos Myrianthous in any 3 months actually but getting it for last 3 consecutive months is even better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way could be as shown below, assuming you receive the date columns OR have the ability to parse months in date columns.

```
df['months'] = df['months'].apply(lambda x: '01-{}-2019'.format(x))
df['months'] = pd.to_datetime(df['months'])

df['sales_diff'] = df.groupby('seller_id')['sales_amount'].diff(periods=1)
df['sales_diff_sign'] = np.sign(df.sales_diff)

df_sales_3_mo_cnt = df.groupby('seller_id')['sales_diff_sign'].apply(lambda x : (x > 0).sum()).reset_index(name='cnt')
df_sales_3_mo_cnt[df_sales_3_mo_cnt.cnt >2]
```

Comment: Thank you  @VishRajpal but unfortunately I am getting error @ `pd.to_datetime(df['months'])` because of months abbreviation but I guess once that gets fixed rest will work properly. Thanks again!

Comment: I updated the answer by coding date to 01 and year 2019. Like I said, I assume you can get granular dates from the raw data itself and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps in the python portion, not sure about the SQL

```
def last_N_consecutive_period_increase(df,period = 3):
    for seller_df in df.groupby("Seller_id"):
        if(sum(seller_df[1].tail(period+1).Sales_amount.diff(periods = 1)>0) == period):
            yield seller_df[0]

for sales_id in last_N_consecutive_period_increase(df,period = 3):
    print(sales_id)
```

```
def any_N_period_increase(df, period = 3):
    for seller_df in df.groupby("Seller_id"):
        if(sum(seller_df[1].Sales_amount.diff(periods = 1)>0) >= period):
            yield seller_df[0]

for sales_id in any_N_period_increase(df, period = 3):
    print(sales_id)
```

Comment: Thank you @[Yongkang Zhao] for writing such good solution and also giving me options for both consecutive and any 3 months. It worked perfectly as I wanted.

Comment: Glad I can help :)